# What was the first precedent when somebody was expelled from Kingsguard before GOT events?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Kingsguard members serve till the death. But during the events of the books and TV series, some members were expelled. What was the first precedent when somebody was expelled from Kingsguard? For example, if a Knight became completely crippled, or maybe fled to the far East.

Comment: Hmm, can't think of one at the top of my head. As I recall, it was a big deal that Joffrey expelled Barristan as it was unprecedented. In fact, Robb remarks that he should now be able to do the same thing with Jon Snow and the Night's Watch because of it.

Comment: The first place to look is here: [Historical Members of the Kingsguard](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Kingsguard#Historical_Members)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If we are talking about dismissal as in honorable retirement package, Barristan Selmy would be the first. He was the first one to have been dismissed on account of inability to protect the King due to advanced age (Or in reality to give [Sandor](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Sandor_Clegane) a place on the Kingsguard).

While there is no precedent for dismissing a kingsguard knight on physical incapacity, there are cases in which a KG was considered dismissed after he fled or after he broke his Sworn vows. Deserting and breaking your vows virtually amount to the same thing. Quoting Ser [Georld "White Bull" Hightower](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Gerold_Hightower), Lord Cmdr. of KG:

> “Ser Willem Darry is fled to Dragonstone, with your queen and Prince
>   Viserys. I thought you might have sailed with him.”
>
> “Ser Willem is a good man and true,” said Ser Oswell.
>
> “But not of the Kingsguard,” Ser Gerold pointed out. “**The Kingsguard**
>   **does not flee.**”

Before/After him, following sworn brothers were dismissed on following accounts:

### Ante Selmy

1. [Lucamore Strong](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Lucamore_Strong) aka Lucamore the Lusty. Dismissed on charge of breaking his vow of celibacy and sent to wall after being gelded by [Jaehaerys the Conciliator](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Jaehaerys_I_Targaryen) . His dismissal is implied by him being sent to the wall, because according to [Vows of Kingsguard](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Kingsguard#History):

   > During his time as a member of the Kingsguard, a member is not allowed
   >   to hold lands, sire children, marry, or **have any worldly allegiance**
   >   **except to his monarch.**

   and according to [vows of Nights Watch](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Night's_Watch#Vows):

   > **I pledge my life and honor to the Night's Watch**, for this night and
   >   all the nights to come.

   So it is clear that you can't be a member of the Kingsguard and Night's Watch at the same time because that would be conflicting with Vows of both the orders. It is also proven because in the aftermath of Robert's Rebellion,  Ned Stark urged Robert Baratheon to send Ser Jaime Lannister to the wall so that he could no longer serve in position of a Kingsguard. Robert however did not heed to his advice and Jaime continued to serve as a KG. If Robert had listened to Eddard Stark, that would have ended Jaime's commision as a KG and opened a vacant post in the KG.

### Poste Selmy

1. [Boros Blount](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Boros_Blount) dismissed on charge of Cowardice after surrendering Prince Tommen to Tyrion's men. Later reinstated by Lord Tywin.
2. [Sandor Clegane](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Sandor_Clegane) aka the Hound. Dismissed after his desertion during [battle of Blackwater Bay](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Battle_of_the_Blackwater) and later declared an outlaw. It is implied because after he left, Lord Tywin gave his place to Boros Blount in aftermath of the battle. This handles case of your sub-question about what happens if a KG deserts his duty and flees?

There is case of Ser [Terrence Toyne](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Terrence_Toyne) as well but he was executed so one can say he  died a KG and wasn't dismissed despite having an affair with [Aegon](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aegon_IV_Targaryen) the unworthy's [mistress](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Bethany_Bracken).

Answer (score 9):

According to the book, Barristan Selmy is the very first. His dismissal is what sets precedent for any future discussions or incidents along those lines.

In fact, crippled doesn't seem to be a factor, as Jaime seems sure that he will find precedent to stay in the Kingsguard.
As seen in Jaime's second chapter in A Storm of Swords part 2 (his return to King's Landing):

> "It was poison that killed Joffrey, not sorcery." Lord Tywin glanced at Jaime's stump again. "You cannot serve in the Kingsguard without a sword hand-"
>
> "I can," he interrupted. "And I will. **There's precedent. I'll look in the White Book and find it, if you like. Crippled or whole, a knight of the Kingsguard serves for life.**"
>
> "**Cersei ended that when she replaced Ser Barristan on grounds of age**. A suitable gift to the Faith will persuade the High Septon to release you from your vows. **Your sister was foolish to dismiss Selmy, admittedly, but now that she has opened the gates**-"
>
> "- someone needs to close them again." Jaime stood .....

Comment: Jaime talked only about dismissal on account of being a cripple. He does not discuss dismissal of Boros Blount for Cowardice, Sandor Clegane for desertion, Lucamore the lusty for well, being lusty.

Comment: Correct. Bear in mind that Sandor for desertion came after Barristan (and Boros), so that was still the overriding precedent. The case of someone like Lucamore is a weird one - obviously through history, there have been turncloak Kingsguards, and it becomes murky when you have multiple claims (e.g. Dance of the Dragons). In a way, he wasn't "expelled" in the same way so much as Jaehaerys took mercy on him by not executing him while an active member of the Kingsguard. Which is subtly different from Barristan, Boros or Sandor Clegane.

Comment: Turncloak knigths were still Knights of KG and QG during DoD. Neither Aegon II nor Rhaenyra chose more knights to make their respective band to seven. Also you cannot serve in the NW/KG while giving allegiance to another realm/brotherhood, thus Lucamore cannot be a brother of the Nights watch and the KG at the same time. Since he was alive and joined Night's watch, he was no longer a KG.

Comment: Which is why I consider him to be the first KG to be dismissed, not Selmy. Even though Selmy's was honorable discharge and Strong was discharged dishonorably.

Comment: @NSNoob how do you think, if Kingsguard member can leave KG by joining Nightwatch, can king choose one of the Nightwatch members to join Kingsguard?

Comment: @Schullz Their vows make me think that. KG vows to live and die for the King and forsake every other allegiance. NW vows to live and die for the Watch and forsake every other allegiance. While there is no example of a NW being appointed a KG, we do have an example of a KG being sent to wall.

Comment: @NSNoob I think there's more to it than that. He was from that point considered no longer a man, being sent to the NW is a mercy in place of execution. Lucamore is effectively treated as "no longer alive", which is a different thing than being deliberately stripped of your cloak or relieved from your vows. I'd consider him in somewhat the same boat as, say, Terrence Toyne.

Comment: I don't see any implication as to how he would be seen as no longer alive. He took the vows of NW which effectively nullify his previous vows as KG. Hence he wasn't a KG anymore but he was very much alive

Comment: That's the essence of a Night's Watch sentence in place of an execution. The same happens with Ned Stark. It's a "You did a crime whose punishment is execution, but instead of killing you, we'll just send you away and you'll be dead to the world anyway". Sometimes it's a mercy; in this case it was probably done to increase his suffering after he had his bits lopped off. Nothing he did, or could do, mattered after his sentence, and as far as people were concerned probably even less so because he "wasn't even a man anymore".

Comment: Night's Watch induction is granted as a chance to redeem one's honor or to neutralize his political influence as NW vows take care of that or also as mercy in some cases. By using your logic, one could say Most men of the Night's watch were not men at all which is of course not true. Those who join the Watch are not considered "dead" by the outside world. Neglected yup, but dead? No. I'd be happy if you would share any canon evidence that says otherwise. For example Ulmer was an outlaw but he served loyally and honorably in the Watch.

Comment: One could also say Brynden Rivers aka Bloodraven is not a man or alive either because King Aegon V sent him to the wall while in fact He is probably the most manliest man ever.

Comment: The "not really a man" part refers to Lucamore being "gelded" (having his penis chopped off, in case the term is unfamiliar), not to him joining the Night's Watch.

The punishment for breaking his vows was execution, which was "replaced" with being sent to the Wall - the gelding, well... who knows, apparently the King was in a bad mood that day, or (more likely) it was to set an example, considering Lucamore didn't just break his vow once, but to the extent that he (apparently) fathered 16 children...